# Magento 1.9 - PayPal gateway has rejected request error

Tags: paypal, paypal-express, magento1.9.2.3

Mail remainder,

> Payment transaction failed. Reason PayPal gateway has rejected
>   request. A successful transaction has already been completed for this
>   token (#10415: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See
>   additional error messages for details).
>
> Checkout Type onepage
>
> Customer: Abc (abc@gmail.com)
>
> Items abc x 1 USD 11 
>    xyz x 1 USD 10 Total: USD 33.93

What is the main cause for this above error?